# Need to know about Salesforce User Licences

Tags: licenses, userlicense, editions

My client is going to buy '**Lightning Enterprise ($150/User)**' and he need to reduce cost of other users and he want to buy 100 Users of '**Lightning Professional ($75/user)**', After purchasing of these all users he needs to connect Lightning professional's User to Lightning EnterPrise Edition

Is it Possible way to reduce cost of salesforce licenses ?

Answer (score 1):

This would only be possible by implementing Salesforce to Salesforce as a single Salesforce Org can only include **one** licence type for Salesforce users.I suspect the cost of running 2 orgs connected like this would outweigh any saving on the licence costs. Documentation for Salesforce2Salesforce [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce)

A better option may be to use Salesforce Lightning Enterprise and depending on the use case other internal licences such as Salesforce Platform, Force.com One App or Company Community user. Details of those are [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=0&language=en_US). Chatter

Comment: Do they(LIghtning Professional user) have access of salesforce Data Like Creating Product and Price after choosing Salesforce2Salesforce ?

Comment: I would not be certain as I have never tried implementing Salesforce like this. I really would not recommend it if one of the other internal user licences would work.

Comment: Multi Org Strategy  i think should be avoided.